# Merge Multiple (setup) Files into Single Setup

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, sccm, advanced-installer

I have a project (Outlook desktop add-in) in the following stack:

1. C#
2. Dot net pre-requisite 4.5.2+

When I build the application, I get a setup folder of 3 files/folders:

1. setup.exe
2. project-vsto.vsto
3. Application Files - folder with dll.deploy and manifest files

When I run this exe manually, I can see the installation in my control panel and things work fine.

Now, for mass deployment purposes, I package this folder using advanced installer, through which I create a packaged msi of the project.

On manual installation of this msi, it does 2 things:

1. "Installs" the packaged project. It can be seen in the control panel. However, this is not the actual thing, more like extraction of files in "C:\program-files..." and we need to run the "setup.exe" here.
2. Runs the setup.exe, as it is mentioned in the exit dialog at the time of msi creation. This is actual project installation step.

However, when I deploy this through SCCM or GFI (Languard) (which we will be using for mass deployment), second step does not follow. What is the work-around through this?

Is there any thing in advanced installer which I can do to omit step-1? I have read docs etc but could not find other than doing this through custom actions or exit dialog (I've tried both, obvs) which behave in same way as far as my situation is concerned.

Or,
Can I tweak some setting in SCCM or GFI (maybe add custom action there, or some installation switch, or some other setting?!!) which can help me achieve my purpose.

Any leads which can help my cause will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I follow this correctly there is a **`setup.exe`** in the deployed folder structure after installation, and this needs to run afterwards. What tool created this **`setup.exe`** and what does it actually install? Drivers?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Project build is done in Visual Studio and this setup.exe is add-in to outlook desktop. Only pre-requisite is `.NET 4.5.2+` and all other requirements in form of dll or manifest files are already wrapped in the msi.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you didn't use the built-in support Advanced Installer has for Office addins.

Here it is a video tutorial about how to create a setup package for an Office Addin with Advanced Installer:

[Package Office addin with Advanced Installer](https://youtu.be/BFp2m3kV_Lw)

Try to follow these steps and check the outcome.

Comment: This does not help. That setup also fails to install when done using "silent" switch.

Comment: have you tried creating an MSI installation log and see what exactly fails during the silent install process?

Comment: On installing through cmd, `msiexec /i project.msi /q /qn /S`, it is popping up a dialog box to ask whether it should proceed with installation or not. I think here is the main issue, bcoz if silent mode was running as it was supposed to, we wouldn't see the pop-up dialog.

Comment: I believe you're using the msiexec switches incorrectly. If you want to install it silently without any dialogue boxes you should used "/qn". I'd recommend giving this a read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options